# Can we post on authorized-user's friends walls with offline_access and stream_publish?

Tags: facebook

I wanted to ask a question...

Let's say there are 2 people: Peter and Paul.

1) Peter goes to my app and authorizes it (stream_publish, offline_access and everything else what's necesary).

2) He is now in the app and let's say there is an option like this: Send gift to your friend Paul.

3) Can we post now on the wall of Paul, even he didn't authorized the app?

Thanks for all your answers,
Really apprciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Says it right in [the documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions)

> publish_stream    Enables your
>   application to post content, comments,
>   and likes to a user's stream **and to
>   the streams of the user's friends**,
>   without prompting the user each time.

Comment: Is it possible to post on friend's walls or on user's own wall **only** with the permission of `offline_access' permission?